# Converting a string representation of a constant into a constant?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to accept a formatting constant from a data cell, so I have a string "xlTotalsCalculationAverage". How can I translate that into the Excel constant it represents; the constant `xlTotalsCalculationAverage` is equal to the integer 2.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(RemainingHeader).TotalsCalculation = xlTotalsCalculationAverage
```

is a static representation.

```
TargetTotal = something("xlTotalsCalculationAverage")
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(RemainingHeader).TotalsCalculation = TargetTotal
```

is my goal.

I could make a huge case or switch statement, but it seem silly to duplicate all the possible values.

How can I make Excel convert this string to a known constant value?

Comment: The value of `xlTotalsCalculationAverage` is 2. How are you storing the value in that string?

Comment: My bad, looking at the wrong table row. But that's really not the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's always this:

```
Sub Tester()
    MsgBox WhatIsTheValue("xlTotalsCalculationAverage")
    MsgBox WhatIsTheValue("xlTotalsCalculationCountNums")
End Sub



Function WhatIsTheValue(s As String) As Variant

        Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
        Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
        Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("modTemp")
        Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

        With CodeMod
            .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
            .InsertLines 1, "Public Function GetEnumVal()"
            .InsertLines 2, "GetEnumVal = " & s
            .InsertLines 3, "End Function"
        End With
        WhatIsTheValue = Application.Run("GetEnumVal")

End Function
```

But really - don't do that.

Comment: Wow, that's just... wow. Creating a temporary program & module just to evaluate a constant... I won't do that.

Comment: Well, that was your only option! I think you're stuck with creating a `Select` block to handle the translation: in fact I'd say that's a much better approach, since you can then use more "human readable" options.  I'd would rather be selecting from a list with values like "Average" than "xlTotalsCalculationAverage" ...

Comment: @Demosthenex: If you do not plan to distribute the code then I might have a solution for you using `TLIApplication` Let me know if you are interested?

Comment: What we're agreeing on here is that Excel has no true "evaluate", and no easy way to say LookupInConstantSymbolTable(string)... I was hoping for a straightforward way, I'll just make a case block instead. The duplication is annoying, but this is VBA.

Comment: One has to [add a reference to the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 library](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1f8d4fc9-d5a5-433d-bf07-92ca493f01d4/programmatically-adding-references-vbide-is-not-recognized?forum=exceldev) prior to using this code. And "modTemp" should be a previously existing module.

Comment: I tried this, and could not make it work. Issues: 1) I entered `=WhatIsTheValue("vbOKCancel")` in a cell formula, and I got 0 instead of 1. 2) Adding `Debug.Print WhatIsTheValue` at the end of the function shows that, after pressing *Enter* in the cell formula, it keeps entering `WhatIsTheValue` (new `1`'s are continuously added in the immediate window). 3) When trying to save the workbook I get a dialog "Calculation is incomplete. Recalculate before saving?". 4) Even after pressing *Reset* in the VB IDE, `1`'s keep popping. All are probably symptoms of the same.

Comment: I never tested it as a worksheet function - code run in that way has significant restrictions when compared to a "regular" (called from VBA) function. I'm not surprised it has issues as a UDF.

Comment: Better approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230772/is-there-a-way-to-test-if-a-chart-in-excel-has-its-series-stacked-or-not/27234857#27234857

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no really practical solution, you're generally stuck writing your own switch statements. Since the enums of the .NET Interop Libraries and VBA are, as far as I know, always the same, I wrote a program that generates VBA modules for each public enum inside a (list of) dll's. Here's the output for my Office.Core, PowerPoint, Word, Excel, Publisher and Outlook dll's:

https://gitlab.com/jbjurstam/VbaHelpers/tree/master/GenerateVbaEnumHelpers/bin/Release/output

Here's an example of the code it generates for each enum:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "wMsoHyperlinkType"
Function MsoHyperlinkTypeFromString(value As String) As MsoHyperlinkType
    If IsNumeric(value) Then
        MsoHyperlinkTypeFromString = CInt(value)
        Exit Function
    End If

    Select Case value
        Case "msoHyperlinkRange": MsoHyperlinkTypeFromString = msoHyperlinkRange
        Case "msoHyperlinkShape": MsoHyperlinkTypeFromString = msoHyperlinkShape
        Case "msoHyperlinkInlineShape": MsoHyperlinkTypeFromString = msoHyperlinkInlineShape
    End Select
End Function

Function MsoHyperlinkTypeToString(value As MsoHyperlinkType) As String
    Select Case value
        Case msoHyperlinkRange: MsoHyperlinkTypeToString = "msoHyperlinkRange"
        Case msoHyperlinkShape: MsoHyperlinkTypeToString = "msoHyperlinkShape"
        Case msoHyperlinkInlineShape: MsoHyperlinkTypeToString = "msoHyperlinkInlineShape"
    End Select
End Function
```

Admittedly, it's not practical to include thousand modules in your project, but it's quite rare that you really need this kind of functionality, so I'd just include the things I need at the particular occasion.