# VBA - converting "xlMedium" to constant xlMedium

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to format a given range . The BorderStyle property of a class in the code below has "xlMedium" as value which is of string data type, but weight property needs xlMedium as a constant , how do I convert this string value into a constant ?

Thank you.

```
Function applyFormat(ByRef objRng As clsRange)

 ' Select the Range

     Worksheets(objRng.SheetName).Select

     Worksheets(objRng.SheetName).Range(objRng.RangeValue).Select

            With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
                 .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                 .ColorIndex = 0
                 .TintAndShade = 0
                 .Weight = (Me.BorderStyle)
            End With

            With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
                 .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                 .ColorIndex = 0
                 .TintAndShade = 0
                 .Weight = (Me.BorderStyle)
            End With

End Function
```

Comment: See Tim's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036711/converting-a-string-representation-of-a-constant-into-a-constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple way to convert from a string to its equivalent enum member.

You should change to `BorderStyle as XlBorderWeight` and use the explicit integer values, if you don't you would need to lookup each member manually;

```
public property get BorderStyleValue() as XlBorderWeight   
   select case Me.BorderWeight 
      case "xlMedium": BorderStyleValue= XlBorderWeight.xlMedium
      case "xlThick" : BorderStyleValue= XlBorderWeight.xlThick
      ...

...

.weight = Me.BorderStyleValue
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I am wondering if we can use Evaluate function here some way , I don't know exactly how.

Comment: The built-in .evaluate is for worksheet functions only, there is this monstrosity; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036711/converting-a-string-representation-of-a-constant-into-a-constant or you could do it with a dependency on the typelib info library, or possibly a reference to the script control but doing it that way is pretty nasty.