# Defining variable names using other variables in VBA

Tags: vba, variables

I'm fairly new to VBA, and have the following situation from a basic training exercise:

```
Select Case Me.comColour
    Case Is = "Red"
    Range("a1").Font.Color = vbRed
    Case Is = "Blue"
    Range("a1").Font.Color = vbBlue
    Case Is = "Green"
    Range("a1").Font.Color = vbGreen
End Select
```

Now, given that the combobox only contains the words Red, Green, Blue, it occurred to me that perhaps I could call vb(colour) directly in some manner by saying something like "evaluate vb followed by Me.comColour"

I know I can do this in mIRC scripting to define variables with different names based on other variables (for instance creating %variable1, %variable2, etc as needed) using the format

```
 [ % $+ stuff $+ [ %variable ] ]
```

but how would I do this in VBA?

Comment: I tried with Evaluate("vb" & "Red"). That doesn't work. Evaluate(vbRed) works but this is no solution for your question.

Comment: Some scripting languages allow for that type of behaviour as they are free to re-evaluate themselves "on demand", VBA however runs after a single pass compile so such features are not available. Mapping an identifier in a string to a symbol in code usually involves some kind of lookup.

Comment: Not recommending this approach, but...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036711/converting-a-string-representation-of-a-constant-into-a-constant/10037332#10037332

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in a simple, obvious, way. Something can be done by creating a Dictionary, but I think it is more trouble than it is worth for such a simple code. The `Select Case` would be good enough for me.

[You could create an array and use the index number from the combobox to select the colour, but this is problematic if the order of the combobox items changes.]

BTW You don't need `Is` when comparing for equality:

```
Select Case Me.comColour
    Case "Red"
    Range("a1").Font.Color = vbRed
    Case "Blue"
    Range("a1").Font.Color = vbBlue
    Case "Green"
    Range("a1").Font.Color = vbGreen
End Select
```

You might consider it slightly neater to use `With..End With`:

```
With Range("A1").Font
    Select Case Me.comColour
        Case "Red"
        .Color = vbRed
        Case "Blue"
        .Color = vbBlue
        Case "Green"
        .Color = vbGreen
    End Select
End With
```

but this is a matter of opinion.

Comment: I accept that for this particular piece of code it is probably not worth it, but I got a fair amount of use out of changing variable names in mIRC, so it would be nice to at least know how if I come across a situation where I'd need it. I'm a mathematician, I like complicated...

Comment: Well vbRed can be replaced with `RGB(255,0,0)`, vbGreen with `RGB(0,255,0)`. So you could create an array and use the index number of the combobox to set the corresponding parameter of RGB() to 255 ;)