# CallByName not working for all objects/functions

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA, most Excel functions are either accessible through `Application.WorksheetFunction` or `VBA`

Take `sinh` and `sin` for example:

#### Worksheet Function

```
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.sinh(5)
 74,2032105777888
```

#### VBA Function

```
Debug.Print VBA.sin(5)
-0,958924274663138
```

## Question:

Why does `CallByName` not work on both Worksheet functions and VBA functions?

#### Worksheet Function

```
Debug.Print CallByName(Application.WorksheetFunction, "sinh", VbGet, 5)
 74,2032105777888
```

#### VBA Function

```
Debug.Print CallByName(VBA, "sin", VbGet, 5)
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `CallByName` is actually `VBA.CallByName`...

Comment: `? typename(VBA)` gives an error "Expected variable or procedure, not project"  `VBA` is not an object - maybe more like a namespace (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call signature of `CallByName`... which is actually a member of `VBA.Interaction` as seen below (so your snippet is equivalent to `VBA.Interaction.CallByName(VBA, "sin", VbGet, 5)` or just `VBA.CallByName...`, in any case a side point):

[image]

is

> `CallByName(Object As Object, ProcName As String, CallType As VbCallType, Args() As Variant)`

As `VBA` is not an `Object`, but the standard VBA library, this throws a type mismatch error.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. The exact reason for why I want this is a bit complicated, but it is part of a some testing scripts to test the numerical similarity between some excel functions and functions from other languages.
Do you know perhaps of any way to accomplish an indirect call to VBA functions outside WorkbookFunction, like "sin" and "cos" and "month"? Application.Run also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You could modify this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036711/converting-a-string-representation-of-a-constant-into-a-constant/10037332#10037332

Comment: @TimWilliams - yeah that might be the only way to go... except you ended the answer with "But really - don't do that."

Comment: That was just to head off the complaints about "I tried this and my house caught fire..."  ;-)

Comment: That is Amazing! VBA/Excel is in any case a fire hazard, I keep it as far away from production code as possible

Comment: As a follow up to Simon, You can run Excel commands and VBA commands from C# or VB.NET if you want to evaluate multiple languages you might want to get your test suite in to Visual Studio where you can do any sort of wizardry you want.

Answer (score 3):

> In VBA, most Excel functions are either accessible through Application.WorksheetFunction or VBA

No. Excel functions are accessible as late-bound member calls against the global `Excel.Application` object (if you're hosted in Excel), and then some have an early-bound "equivalent" (error handling strategy will need to differ) in the `Excel.WorksheetObject` interface (you get it from `Application.WorksheetFunction` indeed).

The members of the `VBA` library, global-scope or not, have nothing to do with Excel: the VBA standard library is referenced by every VBA project, regardless of its host application (Word, Excel, Access, ...SolidWorks, Sage300, etc.). If a function looks like it exists in both the VBA and the Excel libraries, the VBA function should probably/theoretically be preferred.

Use the object browser (F2) to discover the members of the VBA standard library, including and perhaps particularly its `Math` module.