# VBA Word - Using a string variable to define highlight color index property

Tags: vba, ms-word, highlight

I am trying to make a macro that extracts information from one file and applies certain elements to a different file.

The first Word file contains, amongst other things, information for highlight colour. So far, I've tried extracting this information (e.g., "wdgray25") as a string and then defining `docrange.highlightcolorindex = mystring`.

However, this obviously doesn't work because it's a string value rather than just the information. I want to avoid doing loads of if/then loops (e.g., `if mystring = "wdgray25" then docrange.highlightcolorindex = wdgray25`) because there are 15 possible values and this seems inefficient. Is there any better way to define this property depending on a found value?

I've found this problem quite difficult to express so please let me know if I can explain further.

EDIT: Here's the relevant snippet of my code so far (ESPHCI is the colour index string):

````
masterdoc.Activate
Set srange = masterdoc.Range

'2.3 Insert highlights in acc doc.

accdoc.Activate
docrange = activedocument.range

fullarray = Split(srange, vbCr)
max = UBound(fullarray) - 1

ESPHCI = Split(fullarray(0), ":")

For i = 1 To max

With docrange.Duplicate
With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = fullarray(i)
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = Yes
End With
Do While .Find.Execute(Forward:=True) = True
        .HighlightColorIndex = ESPHCI(1)
      Loop
End With

Next i```
````

Comment: Make a function with a Select Case which maps the strings to the actual Word constant.

Comment: Previously here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036711/converting-a-string-representation-of-a-constant-into-a-constant/10037332#10037332  Question is about Excel VBA but the same things apply here.  See the "Select Case" answer there.